# Connection to SQL Server on the same domain takes time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dns, cross-domain

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to 192.168.15.101.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Connection Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement. This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time. The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=34770; handshake=23624;  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -2)

Comment: Check you sql server configuration has TCP/IP and Names pipes in Enable mode

Comment: Check the SQL Server Configuration tool's Server Protocol settings to see that it not only has the TCP/IP protocol enabled but that it is also listening on its Public IP address (not just 127.0.0.1 as some editions of SQL Server are wont to do).